# How can i remove URLmapping when i already public to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

In my web.config, I setting like below because i want redirect to ~/layout/asp

```
<urlMappings enabled="true"> 
<add mappedUrl="~/layout/asp" url="~/"/>
</urlMappings>
```

But later, i don't want redirect anymore, i was delete above code in web.config and public to IIS but it still redirect to  layout/asp
I think IIS is save my setting 
It working correct when i run on debug environment in visual studio

Comment: When i redeploy to IIS with different name, it's work fine, but redeploy with same name, problem will appear. So i think there must be save info somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Restart your IIS: `iisreset /restart`

Comment: full iis restart, and what if he have 200 sites ? Maybe if he just restart the current site only by open the `app_offline.htm`

Comment: i was try restart and still the same